# Accessing the HTML of a page in Google

Tags: javascript, api, same-origin-policy

I'm pretty aware of the *Same Origin Policy*, but the point is, what I want to access does not include JavaScript tags, Head tags or anything of that sort.

What I want to have access to, is something similar to [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=laliga&rlz=1C1GGRV_enIR769IR769&oq=laliga&aqs=chrome.0.0i67i355j46i67j46i512j0i10i512j0i512j46i512j0i512l4.2060j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sie=lg;/g/11sqj24s0_;2;/m/09gqx;st;fp;1;;;) page. (It's not exactly this page, but a standing table for another league)

I want to use the online status of the teams for a local file and customize the table,(Including its translation to my mother language)
so 'iframing' won't do the trick.

I'm pretty aware that I cannot fetch the data using the simple import methods that you use for importing data from the same domain, and it *is* not 'the same domain'. So I'll have security and *SOP* issues.

But I wondered if there's an API or method for fetching data that is not risky to fetch for the clients and Google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of thing should involve server side to fetch the data. Because it is not restricted to same origin policy because it is not a browser. So you won't have CORS issue. So the challenge is just to extract the info itself.

Here's a small [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) script that might fetch you the first page in the series of pages and scripts to load. It won't be easy at all.

```js
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

var url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=laliga&rlz=1C1GGRV_enIR769IR769&oq=laliga&aqs=chrome.0.0i67i355j46i67j46i512j0i10i512j0i512j46i512j0i512l4.2060j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sie=lg;/g/11sqj24s0_;2;/m/09gqx;st;fp;1;;;';
async function run() {

    var browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    var page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    var result = await page.$eval("body", (element) => {
        return element.innerHTML
      })
    browser.close();

    console.log(result);
}
run();
```